# How to make sums in exponents look good?

Tags: pdftex

I want to use the phrase

```
e^{\theta\sum_{k=1}^n x_k}
```

in a stand-alone equation (i.e. `\[ ... \]`). When displayed, this does not look great; the summation symbol is small and compressed. What can I do to make this look nice?

Comment: ...alternatively, define the sun as another symbol and use that in the exponent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're sliding into the realms of typesetting advice, which is usually considered too broad and/or primarily opinion based.

Anyway, what you should do here is consider `\exp`, i.e.:

```
\[
  \exp\left(\theta \sum_{k = 1}^{n} x_{k}\right)
\]
```

[image]

This notation has the same meaning as `e^{...}`

In other news, the summation symbol should be small and compressed if you are intent on using the actual superscript notation, this is absolutely by design and it will be hard to read and ridiculous-looking if you force your exponent to dwarf your base.

Compare:

[image]

However, if you had a deep, irrational hatred for your reader, you would do it like this :P

```
\[
  e^{\displaystyle \left(\theta \sum_{k = 1}^{n} x_{k}\right)}
\]
```

This will have the additional side-effect of using the full-size font, unfortunately, which we could correct for this using the `\scalebox` command from the `graphicx` package:

```
\[
  e^{\scalebox{0.7}{$\displaystyle \left(\theta \sum_{k = 1}^{n}
        x_{k}\right)$}}
\]
```

[image]

Can't you just tell that you're doing something you shouldn't?

For me this is *better*, but then the bar was pretty low! :P

Comment: You answered both the question that I asked with the bottom expression, and proved that I was asking the wrong question by saying to do it with \exp. Thank you.

Comment: Using `\left` and `\right` to auto-size the parentheses gives inferior results, typographically speaking, in almost all cases. In the `\exp` case, `\exp\biggl(\theta \sum_{k = 1}^{n} x_{k}\!\biggr)` would be preferable. (The `\!` directive is optional.) For inline math mode (aka text style), using `e^{...}` notation is going to be unsatisfactory; \exp\bigl(\theta\sum_k\! x_k\bigr) is kinder on the readers' eyes. By the way, stating the upper limit of summation is probably not necessary for inline math mode usage.